# Passing style as property to nested React components

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, jsx

This is a simplified version of my problem, so I hope I can get the point across. I have a React Component that is a parent to many other components, who should all have the same style applied to each component that is nested. I mainly just want to DRY things up.

```
const compStyle = `.user-section{
                      padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
                      background: #f8f8f8;
                      margin-bottom: 15px;
                      border-radius: 2px;
                      min-height: 225px;
                      border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
                    }
                    .dog{
                      text-align: right;
                    }`


class PetsIndex extends React.Component {

  render(){

    return (
      <UserInfo style={compStyle}/>
      <PetsInfo style={compStyle}/>
    )
  }
}
```

In each component, I am applying the style with a Style tag, so it looks like `<style>{this.props.style}</style>`.

So the style is getting there, but for some reason it will not read the first selector and apply the styles. For example, in the code above, with how the order is right now, it will apply the style belonging to the `.dog` class, but not the `.user-section` class. But if I switch the order to:

```
               `.dog{
                  text-align: right;
                }
                .user-section{
                  padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
                  background: #f8f8f8;
                  margin-bottom: 15px;
                  border-radius: 2px;
                  min-height: 225px;
                  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
                }`
```

The results are flipped and the `.dog` styles are not applied and the `.user-section` styles are applied. I did find out that if I put something random first like:

```
               `div{}
                .user-section{
                  padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
                  background: #f8f8f8;
                  margin-bottom: 15px;
                  border-radius: 2px;
                  min-height: 225px;
                  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
                }
                .dog{
                  text-align: right;
                }`
```

I find that it works just fine and I have all the style that I need. Is this a current bug? Or am I missing something?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you putting the ` at the end of the text-align property ? Is this in your code ? If so, that's a problem.

Comment: @RafaelBerro Sorry that's a typo on the posting, the code does not reflect that, I'll fix the typo above.

Comment: I could use `<style jsx global>` on the parent component...

Comment: Try to apply the styles as you would do if it was inline, like this. ````const myStyle = "padding: 2rem 2.5rem; background: #f8f8f8; margin-bottom: 15px; border-radius: 2px; min-height: 225px; border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09); text-align: right;";````